# aws-sdk "Could not find API configuration s3-2006-03-01"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, require, aws-sdk-js

I'm writing this service that writes files to s3, and I sporadically come across this `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error. The message is `"Could not find API configuration s3-2006-03-01"`. It seems to happen in clusters (multiple calls to this function will all error, then another request later won't error), and I've never encountered this error locally.

I'm not passing an explicit configuration reference to `new AWS.S3()`, but that doesn't really seem to be the issue... If you've encountered/resolved this, would be very interested to hear from you.

error and stack as follows:

```
{
    "message":"Could not find API configuration s3-2006-03-01",
    "name":"MODULE_NOT_FOUND",
    "stack":"MODULE_NOT_FOUND: Could not find API configuration s3-2006-03-01
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.get [as 2006-03-01] (.../node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/s3.js:11:17)
        at Object.apiLoader (.../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/api_loader.js:5:33)
        at Function.defineServiceApi (.../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/service.js:575:22)
        at features.constructor.getLatestServiceClass (.../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/service.js:91:19)
        at features.constructor.loadServiceClass (.../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/service.js:81:19)
        at features.constructor.Service [as constructor] (.../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/service.js:27:29)
        at new features.constructor (.../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:602:24)
        at .../app/async/worker.js:122:20
        at Promise._execute (.../node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:303:9)
        at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (.../node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:483:18)
        at new Promise (.../node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10)
        at s3upload (.../app/async/worker.js:121:12)",
    "code":"MODULE_NOT_FOUND"
}
```

.../node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/s3.js code as follows (the referenced files are all there, and it doesn't seem to produce an error all the time):

```
require('../lib/node_loader');
var AWS = require('../lib/core');
var Service = AWS.Service;
var apiLoader = AWS.apiLoader;

apiLoader.services['s3'] = {};
AWS.S3 = Service.defineService('s3', ['2006-03-01']);
require('../lib/services/s3');
Object.defineProperty(apiLoader.services['s3'], '2006-03-01', {
  get: function get() {
    var model = require('../apis/s3-2006-03-01.min.json');
    model.paginators = require('../apis/s3-2006-03-01.paginators.json').pagination;
    model.waiters = require('../apis/s3-2006-03-01.waiters2.json').waiters;
    return model;
  },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});

module.exports = AWS.S3;
```

My code (`/app/async/worker.js`) that calls into this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

function s3upload(file_location, upload_name, bucket, public = false) {
    return new BPromise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const s3 = new AWS.S3();    // STACK TRACE REFERENCES THIS LINE
        let body = fs.createReadStream(file_location);

        let upload_options = {
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: upload_name,
            Body: body
        };

        if (public) {
            upload_options.ACL = 'public-read';
        }

        s3.upload(upload_options, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            resolve(data.Location);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Not sure it helps or is still relevant, but I had the same issue with aws-sdk-mock and the issue was somewhere completely different. You could try to wrap the `new AWS.S3()` in a `try/catch` and log what comes out. Maybe you get a step further

Comment: interesting note, thanks for the idea @LucHendriks!

Comment: hi, may I ask, did you find the solution for this question?

Comment: @cauldyclark nope, it's infrequent enough that it's not causing meaningful issues.

Comment: I ran into it when I was waiting on a promise from the "got" npm, and then called "new S3()". I switched the order, called S3 first and then ran the promise and it worked. I also tried switching libraries, to fetch and node-fetch, no luck. Only thing that worked was getting that S3 object before waiting on any HTTP requests.

Comment: I had the same issue when I mocked fs.readFileSync. to solve the issue I used fs-extra library instead fs. mocking fs-extra.readFileSync skips the problem.